# WiX - uninstall patch but leave file

Tags: wix, wix3.8

Hi im [Using Purely WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/patching/wix_patching.html) patching method. I've got problem with uninstall, because I modify some files and patch won't replace them - what is good, but now when i uninstall patch that file that wasn't replaced back to base state.

Little example:
I'm installing V1 *file1.txt* and *file2.txt*. I added 1 line to *file1.txt*. Now I'm using patch with *file1.txt* and *file2.txt* these files were modify in patch. *file1.txt* was modify ealrlier so patch doesn't replace it, *file2.txt* was in oryginal state so it was replaced. Everything fine, but now I'm uninstalling patch ("Programs" then "View installed updates" in the Control panel). **File1.txt** is replaced to state when I was installing V1! So i lost that 1 line i added earlier... *file2.txt* also back to that state - but its good.

***Question***:
Is there way to save **file1.txt** state on uninstall patch? But with condition if *file1.txt* was in oryginal state then take *file1.txt* from V1 installer (like *file2.txt*)